# How to search for Sitecore media items over certain filesize in XPath builder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

The XPath builder is available from the Sitecore 'developer center'. Start > Developer Center > Tools > XPath Builder. I'm using sitecore query notation.

I would like to search for media items over a certain filesize -

```
/sitecore/media library//*[@size > 99999]
```

This does a string compare on the size, so the 'greater than' doesn't work as expected.

```
/sitecore/media library//*[Number(@size) > 99999]
```

This works as expected, but trips up when it encounters an item with no filesize - for example folders. I've tried a few permutations to filter out these items without success. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be something cleaner, but this works:

```
/sitecore/media library//*[@size!='']/.[Number(@size) > 99999]
```

Note that the line below does not work, since **and** in XPATH does not have the "short-circuit" functionality that **&&** has in C#.

```
/sitecore/media library//*[@size!='' and Number(@size) > 99999]
```

Comment: Many thanks, it was the 'short circuit' aspect that was the problem.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!  Sitecore's XSL Reference on SDN was very helpful in researching this. http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/presentationcomponentxslreference-a4.pdf#search=%22xslt%22